# R consolidate dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        mCodes    datetime
1           61    2012_10_28_19
2           61    2012_10_28_19
3           63    2012_10_28_19
4           63    2012_10_28_20
5        10_61    2012_10_28_20
6           61    2012_10_28_20
7           61    2012_10_28_20
8           61    2012_10_28_21
9           61    2012_10_28_21
10       10_65    2012_10_28_21
11       10_63    2012_10_28_21
12       10_63    2012_10_28_22
13          61    2012_10_28_22
14          63    2012_10_28_22
15          61    2012_10_28_22
16          61    2012_10_28_22
17          61    2012_10_28_23
18          61    2012_10_28_23
19       10_61    2012_10_28_23
20       10_61    2012_10_28_23
```

and I want to end up with this:

```
        mCodes    datetime
1        61_63    2012_10_28_19
2     10_61_63    2012_10_28_20
3     10_61_65    2012_10_28_21
4     10_61_63    2012_10_28_22
5        10_61    2012_10_28_23
```

I know this is possible with a for loop, but the problem is, this is part of a much larger dataset and for loops are very inefficient.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate` for this:

```
aggregate(mCodes ~ datetime, data=unique(dat, MARGIN=1),
          function(z) {
              paste(sort(ifelse(grepl('_',z), unlist(strsplit(as.character(z),'_')), z)), collapse='_')
          })
```

Result:

```
       datetime   mCodes
1 2012_10_28_19    61_63
2 2012_10_28_20 10_61_63
3 2012_10_28_21 10_61_65
4 2012_10_28_22 10_61_63
5 2012_10_28_23    10_61
```

And your data, as I read it in:

```
dat <- read.table(text='        mCodes    datetime
1           61    2012_10_28_19
2           61    2012_10_28_19
3           63    2012_10_28_19
4           63    2012_10_28_20
5        10_61    2012_10_28_20
6           61    2012_10_28_20
7           61    2012_10_28_20
8           61    2012_10_28_21
9           61    2012_10_28_21
10       10_65    2012_10_28_21
11       10_63    2012_10_28_21
12       10_63    2012_10_28_22
13          61    2012_10_28_22
14          63    2012_10_28_22
15          61    2012_10_28_22
16          61    2012_10_28_22
17          61    2012_10_28_23
18          61    2012_10_28_23
19       10_61    2012_10_28_23
20       10_61    2012_10_28_23', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a `data.table` solution which is specially designed for large data sets.

Say `df` is your data set

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(mCodes = paste(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(unique(mCodes), "_")))), collapse = "_")), by = datetime]

##         datetime      mCodes 
## 1: 2012_10_28_19       61_63
## 2: 2012_10_28_20    10_61_63
## 3: 2012_10_28_21 10_61_63_65
## 4: 2012_10_28_22    10_61_63
## 5: 2012_10_28_23       10_61
```

The only thing I'm straggling to understand is why there is no `63` in `2012_10_28_21` date in your desired output? I can't understand why you decided to take it out